# Tensorboard parsing metadata or fetching sprite images takes forever

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I ran this code snippet:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

LOG_DIR = 'logs'
metadata = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'metadata.tsv')

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data')
input_1 = mnist.train.next_batch(10)
images = tf.Variable(input_1[0], name='images')

with open(metadata, 'w') as metadata_file:
    for row in input_1[1]:
        metadata_file.write('%d\n' % row)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver([images])

    sess.run(images.initializer)
    saver.save(sess, os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'images.ckpt'))

    config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
    # One can add multiple embeddings.
    # Link this tensor to its metadata file (e.g. labels).
    embedding = config.embeddings.add()
    embedding.tensor_name = images.name

    embedding.metadata_path = metadata
    # Saves a config file that TensorBoard will read during startup.
    projector.visualize_embeddings(tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR), config)
```

And after this, I opened tensorboard embedding tab and it showed parsing metadata. However, it kept on loading that way endlessly. I tried another code and in that case, it kept loading on fetching spite Image. Is there something wrong with my tensorboard?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that TensorBoard couldn't find your metadata file, because it looks for the metadata file relative to the directory that you have specified with your '*--logdir*' parameter of the '*tensorboard*' command.

So if you are opening TensorBoard with '*tensorboard --logdir logs*', it will look for the metadata file in 'logs/logs/metadata.tsv'.

A possible fix for your code is to replace this line

```
embedding.metadata_path = metadata
```

with this one:

```
 embedding.metadata_path = 'metadata.tsv'
```

In general, in order to debug errors TensorBoard you have to look at the response of the error messages in your browser console when looking at TensorBoard.